# How can I change Data Source dynamically in XtraReport in WinForms in .Net Core 5

Tags: c#, devexpress, asp.net-core-5.0

I would like to generate an invoice using XtraReport. So far, I have followed these points.
I have a design report using the designer and assign data source from the designer. Now I want to generate a report based on dynamic data. For example, I have a textbook for the bill number. I put any number and click on the button, then I will get filtered data from the database and this data table that I want to assign to my report. I have uploaded screenshot that has the same method (btnPrint_Click). I have also uploaded the other screenshot with data source and datamember information.

FYI : Currently, when I have clicked on the button, then invoice generates  all the data instead of filtered data.

Thank You in Advance.

[Data Source & Data Member Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziu52.png)

[Btn Print method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rosvF.png)

Comment: Please check this ticket. https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/e4657/how-to-dynamically-generate-a-report-and-bind-it-to-a-dataset-in-a-winforms-application

Comment: Also give a try, by setting datasource before report.CreateDocument();

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.